# Open the app from the terminal

Tags: command-line, pencil

[pencil/now 3.1.0.ga-2 amd64 [installed,local]
This is the result of the command I used to list all the installed apps in ubuntu.
But now I need to open the app "Pencil" from the terminal.
How can I open it from the terminal? As I tried by its name but it didn't open from terminal.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? What is pencil? Please add the output of `apt-cache policy pencil` to the question.

Comment: Were it me, I'd look at the files included in the package (`dpkg -L pencil`), and look for the binary. Then I would know what it's called and where it's at.